# How can I make a middleware or util function for my code to be reusable?

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis

I am implementing redis with nodejs, and I am new to it. I am having trouble making my redis implementation reusable for me not to repeat the same code constantly.

This is my controller:

```
const asyncHandler = require('../middleware/async');
const Profile = require('../models/Profile.model');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');

//@desc     Create a Profile
//@route    POST /api/profile
//@access   Private

exports.createProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const redis = require('redis');
    const url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
    const client = redis.createClient(url);
    await client.connect();

    const cached = await client.get('profiles');

    const { biography, profileImageUrl, location, birthdate } = req.body;
    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user_id = req.user.id;

    profileFields.biography = biography;
    profileFields.location = location;
    profileFields.birthdate = birthdate;
    profileFields.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;

    if(biography) profileFields.biography = biography;
    if(profileImageUrl) profileFields.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    if(location) profileFields.location = location;
    if(birthdate) profileFields.birthdate = birthdate;

    let profile = await Profile.findOne({ where: { user_id: req.user.id } });

    if (profile) {
        profile = await profile.update(
            { user: req.user.id },
            { $set: profileFields },
            { new: true } 
        );
    }
    
    profile = await Profile.create(profileFields);
    client.del('profiles');
    res.status(200).json(profile);

});    

//@desc      Get all Profiles
//@route     GET /api/profile
//@access    Public

exports.getProfiles = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const redis = require('redis');
    const url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
    const client = redis.createClient(url);
    await client.connect();

    const cached = await client.get('profiles');
    
    if(cached) {
        console.log('Profiles cached');
        res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(cached));
        return;
    }

    const profiles = await Profile.findAll();
    console.log('Profiles not cached');
    res.status(200).json(profiles);

    
    client.SETEX('profiles',  3600, JSON.stringify(profiles));
});
```

As you can see I am repeating the same lines regarding redis in both of my methods, how can I make a util function or middleware for me to reuse the redis connection in my routes or methods?

Should I pass it to my routes as a middleware or should I create a util function and imported in all of my controllers?

Comment: Just move common code into shared functions and call those shared functions from anyplace you want to use it.  Just like any function design, you can pass in parameters or return values as needed.  For some unknown reason, people seem to completely forget common programming practices (like breaking common code into shared functions) when designing middleware functions.  But, they are just functions like any other Javascript so you can use all the usually programming techniques with them to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: Also, you probably should move your `require()` statements to the top of your module so it's executed once at module startup time.